# Laravel 5 showing directory structure instead of index.php on xampp localhost

Tags: php, .htaccess, xampp, laravel-5

```
http://localhost/laravel_test/
```

Instead of routing to the index.php above URL is only printing Index (Directory Structure) of /laravel_test.

I am able access the index page with following:

```
http://localhost/laravel_test/public/index.php
```

I tried modifying the .htacess file by adding following line inside the public directory of laravel_test still no change:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Comment: What do you see when you open `http://localhost/laravel_test/public/` ?

Comment: http://localhost/laravel_test/public/ I see index.php

Comment: Thats how it is meant to be. If you are running Apache, you can use virtualhost, or edit windows host file to do this. You can also move the contents correctly one level up, if you want it that way, but it may be a pain. http://tutsnare.com/remove-public-from-url-laravel/

Answer (score 2):

This is an old post, but in case this helps anyone, I was facing this problem because my `httpd-vhosts.conf` file was pointing to `C:/xampp/htdocs/MySite` instead of `C:/xampp/htdocs/MySite/public`. This is stupid mistake but you know everyone does this kind of mistakes once in a while.